# Use Regex to capitalize the first letters of the first and last words of a string?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Hopefully the title says it all, but I am wanting to upper case the first letters of both the first and the last words in a string like this:

```
Turn this:
this is a regular sentence

Into this:
This is a regular Sentence
```

Ideally, I'd like it to work on ANY characters such as `à -> À`, but I do not wish to over complicate this if that is a bigger deal to pull off.

Comment: We at StackOverflow like it when the users who ask questions show that they have at least attempted a solution.

Comment: Fair enough. Unfortunately my only attempt was me trying to simply capitalize the first word. I was just about to give up and just use the string library functions in .NET when I decided to pose this question here.

Comment: @crush: you don't speak for all of us

Comment: Why not just split the string on `\s` then capitalize the first and last elements of the array, then join the array back to a string again? No need for overthinking or a fancy RegEx.

Comment: @tenub Have a look at [Are questions describing a problem without showing effort (whether or not attempted) welcome?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80296/204922).

Comment: Good point on the split, @tenub. That would actually work just fine I think.

Comment: @tenub Post it as a solution. It clearly meets the criteria established by the question.

Comment: I guess I don't HAVE to use regex in my personal, but that is how I framed the question in my title, to be fair to @tenub's decision not to put it as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regular expressions alone can't do this, but you can pass a custom [`MatchEvaluator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the [`Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. This can be a lambda expression, like this:

```
var input = "this is a regular sentence";
var output = Regex.Replace(
        input, 
        @"^(?<cap>\w)(?<rest>\w*)|(?<cap>\w)(?<rest>\w*)$", 
        m => m.Groups["cap"].Value.ToUpper() + m.Groups["rest"]);

Console.WriteLine(output); // This is a regular Sentence
```

Notice that in the pattern, I used named groups, so that I wouldn't have to worry about whether I was formatting the first or the last word.

Or perhaps more simply

```
var output = Regex.Replace(
        input, 
        @"^(?<cap>\w)|\b(?<cap>\w)(?=\w*$)", 
        m => m.Groups["cap"].Value.ToUpper());
```

Here, I needed to use a lookahead assertion to identify the last word, but otherwise, the idea is the same.

---

If performance is a big concern, you can always do this:

```
int c = input.LastIndexOf(' ');
var output = 
    char.ToUpper(input[0]) + 
    input.Substring(1, c) + 
    char.ToUpper(input[c + 1]) + 
    input.Substring(c + 2);
```

However, this method does assume that the last word is preceded by a space.

Comment: That is perfect. It is technically uppercasing all the words I believe, correct, but it is only outputting the first and last words? I ask because I gave a simple example in my original post and called it a "sentence", but it may be a very long string. So I wanted to check with you on how you feel the performance would be on a big loop where it might loop through, say, 1000 strings with each string containing 100 words.

Comment: I can't imagine this would win in a battle against @tenub's solution mentioned int he comments above.

Comment: @RandyWhirl No, it's only modifying the first and last words.

Comment: The more I looked at it I came to that same conclusion, @p.s.w.g. Thank you all :)

Comment: @RandyWhirl See my updated answer for a non-regex alternative.